# inner product condition with complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, solution-verification

on $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ we define the  inner product $ < x,y>=x \begin{pmatrix}
1 &\imath  \\ 
 -\imath & 2
\end{pmatrix} y^{\ast }$

i want to show that $ < x,y>$ $ \geq 0$

I consider $x$ to be $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and i calculate  $ < x,x>=\left | x_1 \right |^{2}+2\left | x_2 \right |^{2} +i(\bar{x_2}x_1-x_2\bar{x_1})$ but that's a complex number and it doesn't make sense to have inequalities on complex numbers. Then I thought to just take the norm, but the norm is defined to be $\geq 0$ . Can someone make it more clear for me ?

Comment: Yes I correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x_1=y_1+iz_1$ and $x_2=y_2+iz_2$ where $y_1,y_2,z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{R}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\bar{x}_2x_1-x_2\bar{x}_1&=(y_2-iz_2)(y_1+iz_1)-(y_2+iz_2)(y_1-iz_1) \\
&=[(y_2y_1+z_2z_1)+i(y_2z_1-y_1z_2)]-[(y_2y_1+z_2z_1)+i(y_1z_2-y_2z_1)] \\
&=2i(y_2z_1-y_1z_2). 
\end{align*}
Thus, $$i(\bar{x}_2x_1-x_2\bar{x}_1)=i\cdot 2i(y_2z_1-y_1z_2)=-2(y_2z_1-y_1z_2)\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: Now that I see it written I understand how simple it was. Thanks for taking the time to answering me.

Answer (score 1):

Write $z=\overline{x}_2x_1$.  Then $$\overline{x}_2x_1-x_2\overline{x}_1=z-\overline{z}=2i\Im(z)$$ so the expression you have written is in fact, real.